# GdkDrawingArea on GtkImage

Tags: c, gtk

How can I impose `GdkDrawingArea` on the `GtkImage` for painting on an image, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GtkDrawingArea` and `GtkImage` are different classes, so you must choose one of them. You can still draw on `GtkImage` (and on any other widget), by connecting to `expose_event` signal.

You could also use plain `GtkDrawingArea` - displaying image is a matter of calling `gdk_draw_pixbuf` function.